# How to get Chatter Recommended Users Via Connect Api in apex

Tags: connect-api

I am trying to get the Chatter recommended Users in apex either via ConnectApi or any other means but not via rest Api. I am unable to find any connect Api call that returns me the list of recommended users. Any suggestions how can this be achieved. Any suggestions regarding this would highly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked with the ConnectAPI folks, and unfortunately the recommendations that are available in the Chatter REST API aren't available in the ConnectApi Apex namespace yet.

So at the moment, the only solution available to you would be to make an Apex callout to the Chatter REST API...not pretty...